# How to center this table - HTML/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Meer over <?php echo $user['roepnaam']; ?></h4>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <img src="images/userimg.png" name="aboutme" width="140" height="140" border="0" class="img-circle"></a>
                    <h3 class="media-heading"><?php echo $user['roepnaam']; ?> <?php echo $user['naam']; ?><small> <?php echo $user['stad']; ?></small></h3>

                    <p class="text-left"><strong>Gegevens:</strong><br>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div align="center" class=" col-md-8 col-lg-8 ">
                  <table class="table table-user-information">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Roepnaam:</td>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['roepnaam']; ?></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Naam:</td>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['naam']; ?></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Gebruikersnaam:</td>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['username']; ?></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Woonplaats:</td>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['stad']; ?></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Adres:</td>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['adres1']; ?><br><br><?php echo $user['adres2']; ?></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Provincie:</td>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['provincie']; ?></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Email:</td>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['email']; ?></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </p>
        </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <center>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Sluit</button>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I center my table? I tried everything `margin: 0 auto;` and give a class to the table or id. Tried `<center>` tag but that one should I not be using. Also tried `align: center`; none of those work but I really need to center it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. In the snippet, the table is already centered?!? And that without even using a <center> element! So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is.

From where you have the table div i.e.

```
<div align="center" class=" col-md-8 col-lg-8 ">
      <table class="table table-user-information">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td class="text-left">Roepnaam:</td>
           <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['roepnaam']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-left">Naam:</td>
            <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['naam']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-left">Gebruikersnaam:</td>
            <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['username']; ?></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td class="text-left">Woonplaats:</td>
             <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['stad']; ?></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="text-left">Adres:</td>
              <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['adres1']; ?><br><br><?php echo $user['adres2']; ?></td>
          </tr>
             <tr>
               <td class="text-left">Provincie:</td>
               <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['provincie']; ?></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td class="text-left">Email:</td>
                <td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['email']; ?></td>
               </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Add two divs outside,So that part will now look like this

```
 <div style="width:100%">
        <div style="width:250px; margin:0 auto;">


            <div align="center" class=" col-md-8 col-lg-8 ">
              <table class="table table-user-information">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Roepnaam:</td>
                    <td class="text-left">ewe</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Naam:</td>
                    <td class="text-left">ewe</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Gebruikersnaam:</td>
                    <td class="text-left">wewe</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Woonplaats:</td>
                    <td class="text-left">ewe</td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Adres:</td>
                    <td class="text-left">wewe</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Provincie:</td>
                    <td class="text-left">wewe</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Email:</td>
                    <td class="text-left">ewe</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </div>
            </div>

     </div>
```

Try to make the inner width of div `<div style="width:250px; margin:0 auto;">` to be lower than the outer width of div `<div style="width:100%">` according to your need;

Hope this helps